# Limit git contributors to specified gpg signatures

Tags: git, signature, gnupg, pgp

Can I have in git repository list of gpg signatureas, that are able to make any contributions (including changing that list).

I mean limiting git contributors to only signed and signed by specified (not any) gpg signatures.

Is that possible? If so, which part of git docs describes that?

Comment: How you do this depends on what you're doing for hosting.  Are you using something like GitHub or GitLab, or are you hosting the server yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you operate your own git server, you could implement something like this via e.g. a `pre-receive` hook. You would have to write the code yourself. Hooks are documented [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

If you use GitHub, see their documentation on [Enabling required commit signing](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-commit-signing). That by itself doesn't allow you to limit access, but if you were to combine that with normal repository access control I think you would get close to what you want.